# count 5 in the list without using python built-in function and if condition

Tags: python, list

count 5 in the list without using python built-in function(Count) and if condition. You can use for loop

```
x=[0,5,5,5,0,0,0,5,0,5,0,0]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you saying you're not allowed to use `if` or that you should be using `if` ?

Comment: Will the list always only contain 5 or 0?

Comment: Then I was suggest you sum the values of x (using the for loop) and divide by 5

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the list will only ever contain 0 or 5, then you can sum the list in a for loop and divide the end result by 5 to get the count:

```
x=[0,5,5,5,0,0,0,5,0,5,0,0]
count = 0
for i in x:
    count += i
count = count/5
```

Output:

```
5
```

Comment: I'm new here as don't know much hope i have done what you asked for

Comment: One more question i have please

Comment: Read the text file by removing special character like(@0!). Have to read word by word and remove special character

Suppose text.txt file contains below data

Hi, I am a@man singh ,

i am fr0m Ind!a ,

How are you??

Comment: @Sandeep you should ask it as a new question, especially as it is completely unrelated

Comment: i'm not allowed to ask new question before 90 mins

Comment: @Sandeep then you will have to wait. Perhaps spend those 90 minutes googling/searching on here for an answer, so then you will either solve it yourself, or be able to add what you've tried into your new question

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward solution would be:

```
len(filter(lambda y: y==5, x))
```

but this feels very close to using count...

If you're not supposed to use `len`, then this is a good opportunity to use some functional programming here.

```
from functools import reduce
reduce(lambda _, a: a+1, filter(lambda y: y==5, x))
```

The filter function will filter to only elements which match your criterion (==5) and the reduce function will do the same as a count.